# Looking to write code to match data points by date and time in crystal reports

Tags: crystal-reports

I am looking for help writing a code for crystal reports.  I am trying to filter data where two entries are happening at the same date and time.  I this list of data points but want to match up when there are multiple dates and times that intersect.  Thank you, and hopefully the attached image helps.

[image: crystalreportexample]

Comment: Hi, this could be tricky. It would be helpful to first show what you've tried so far.

Comment: use option `Select Distinct Records` in database label